# Trouble implementing the language accessibility fix on a Kentico Site

Tags: tags, accessibility, kentico

As the title states I am having problems with this,  Utilizing the code Brenden Kehren initally set forth from this thread: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/kentico-9-how-to-define-language-in-html

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentDocument != null)
    {          
        CMS.UIControls.ContentPage page= this.Page as CMS.UIControls.ContentPage;
        if (page != null)
        {
            string lang= CMS.Localization.LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CultureCode;
            page.XmlNamespace += " lang=\"" + lang + "\"";
            page.XmlNamespace += " xml:lang=\"" + lang + "\"";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

however for the life of me I cannot seem to get it to work, keep on getting: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token void

At the line: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

I have placed the code in the header of the master template,  I open the Header Tab, And in the text box under where it says "Add HEAD element content:" I paste in the full snippet that was provided. Including the . Running Kentico 9 if that helps.

It just seems odd that I cannot get this to work.  Any suggestions?

The site is multi cultural with an English and Spanish version, I thought  Kentico was able to auto set up the Language tag in that case but apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the script directly in the layout like this:

[image: script code in kentico]

It should have the following output: (before and after html)

[image: added language tags in html]

Comment: Cool,  I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the layout (where all your zones are), i.e. after the body tag. Secondly CultureCode depends on your URL, your url must contain culture code.

Comment: URL does contain the culture code,   i.e. https://colorado.quitlogix.org/en-US/

I have tried placing the code in the body as well, but still get the error.

Answer (score -1):

This code should go in code behind. Layout need to used for this in code behind section. If you add in HTML segment, browser will not understand this code.

Comment: <script runat="server"> will make it an "embedded Code block" which does get processed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396